# Trouble starting Debug for my game in XNA (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, xna

I've been working on a game project in XNA (vb.net) for a few years now, but I don't have a formal education and so I'm learning while trying. This means I might be writing code inefficiently or simply wrong (good to take into consideration). To my problem:

Today, for the first time, when I start up the debug I get an error before the first frame is drawn (a white window appear). it's highlighting my `game.Run()` with the error  `System.OutOfMemoryException`. When I copy it to clipboard it says:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled
HResult=-2147024882
Message=Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
Source=WindowsGame2
StackTrace:
     at WindowsGame2.Game1.Draw(GameTime gameTime)
     at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.DrawFrame()
     at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Tick()
     at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.HostIdle(Object sender, EventArgs e)
     at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameHost.OnIdle()
     at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.RunOneFrame()
     at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.ApplicationIdle(Object   sender, EventArgs e)
     at   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNat  iveMethods.IMsoComponent.FDoIdle(Int32 grfidlef)
     at   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.Unsafe  NativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID,   Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
     at   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32   reason, ApplicationContext context)
     at   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason,   ApplicationContext context)
     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
     at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.Run()
     at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.RunGame(Boolean useBlockingRun)
     at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run()
     at WindowsGame2.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects  \WindowsGame2\WindowsGame2\WindowsGame2\Program.vb:line 9
InnerException:
```

I cannot recall making any specific changes to the code that day, but to simply add abit more content. I know this is vague, but that's really all I can think of. I've been digging through every forum out there but to no avail. 
Is there any information that I can supply that might be helpful to understand the problem?
I'm thankful for any help!
/Christian

EDIT:
I tried optimizing the code (and quite a bit), so it should run alot smoother once it does. For example, I now use a lot less excessive looping than before.
The problem doesn't seem to be while running it though, but only when it start. Now I get it to start approx 1/5 times that i press debug.

Comment: presumably you use source code revision control? check what changes were made.....

Comment: I didn't know what that even was before googling it now. So no, I'm not using it. Atleast I'm not aware of it, if it's automated. Again though, the only thing I changed about the project was to add some new images and incorporating them (standard prodecure, same every day)

Comment: Use it. Do not develop code without it. (e.g. Use Git.

Comment: I will be looking into that, thank you. As for this question, it doesn't help much at this point

Comment: I should add that the game does start every now and then, after one or two tries.

Comment: download memprofiler (trial used to be free)

Comment: Sounds like a plan. I'll get to it first thing in the morning. I'll keep updating if I encounter any changes. Thank's again

Comment: Any idea what to look for? I am using the tool (memprofiler), but I have no clue what I'm searching for

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the stack trace is pointing you to the Draw method. Make sure you aren't unnecessarily recreating objects every frame (either in draw or update), as this will happen 60 times a second (assuming 60fps).

Since you say it only happens some times, and other times it doesn't, also see if you can reduce what is being created at startup. Make sure you only create what you need when you need it.

If the stack trace is correct and the problem IS in your Draw method specifically, make sure you aren't needlessly recreating textures every frame, and ensure you call .Dispose() on any object that has it when you are done with it.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I don't recreate anything in the drawfunction. However I experienced a slight change to the better when I deleted some of the textureloads in the content.load in beginning. Before I loaded around 1000 textures, now Im at around 950, and I can start the debug around 50% of the tries. If that's the problem, do you know how I can load textures later on instead of at startup?

Comment: Depends on why you are loading that many textures. If it's a level based game, only load the textures required by that level at the level start.

If doing animations, don't use one texture per image, but instead utilize Spritesheets, which are a collection of animations for a specific character (in case you didn't know).

If there aren't levels, and it is instead an RPG style game, look at dividing your world into "tiles", and load and unload when the player is in a certain range of a specific tile.

Also, make your textures as small as you can at a power of 2.

Comment: Yeah it's an RPG roguelike, but not openworld, so would be no big deal for players to wait a few seconds between the "worlds". I just don't know how to do it. I will look into it though, but would appreciate if you know how to do it (in vb.net) and could share! I do know about spritesheets, or to simply have more than one picture per texture. I always tried to optimize that way. What do you mean by making textures small at a power of 2? As for why I load that many textures, is simply because it's so much content, and I don't know how to load it at different times.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you have everything set up right now. I'm assuming you have your "worlds" segregated already. So in your "World" class, you would have a Load method that would make all the Content.Load calls. After you create an instance of the World you would call the load method on that instance. This isn't the most detailed answer, but I'm limited for space.
As for the power of 2 thing, this post gives some information on it: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26187/why-are-textures-always-square-powers-of-two-what-if-they-arent

Comment: Oh hmm I don't think I have it setup that way, since I don't even know how to use "Classes". I just have one code in the Update function I guess (besides some other functions and subs for calculations that happens more than one time). And so if the player beats a boss in one world it simply generates a new one through an algoritm that generates rooms etc.

Comment: No problem, everyone's gotta start somewhere.
However, this begins getting to the point where we are diverging from the original question and possibly entering the realm where the answer will only help you, which doesn't match stackoverflows question styling.
So you can try asking how to separate the loading based on your current setup (I'm sure it can be done), however it won't be an ideal way. What you want to do is look into Object Oriented Programming and learning how to use Classes to organize your code, which will make it more readable and usable. CONTINUED::::

Comment: I gave a quick google search for OOP (Object Oriented Programming) with VB.Net and XNA, but they didn't seem to go into as much detail as I would like. However, OOP concepts are the same across the languages, it's only syntax that differs. Look into some videos or website tutorials on that, follow along (even if it's just accounting logic) and see what you can do with that. Doing this now will reduce the amount of problems you're going to run into in the near future when you start adding more features to the game.

Comment: Yeah I understand we are off topic, though really it's related to the solution of the original post. Thank you alot for the effort, you guys are so important for the community, I just want you to know that. There is literally nobody else I can turn to otherwise. About OOP, do you recommend I look into that with a project already this large? Or would it mean rewrite of all my code basicly? I already have a lot of aspects to pay attention to (painting graphics/composing music/coding) that any extra work is heavy as it is.

Comment: My background is in gaming, so I understand how much you have on your plate. 

You could technically get away with only applying the concepts of OOP to certain parts of your code. But I would assume you would run into a lot of design issues. I don't know how big your project currently is, but I would definitely recommend rewriting it into an Object Oriented structure. As big as it may be now, by the sounds of it it will only get bigger, and if your looking to separate the game into "worlds", OOP will help immensely with that and improve your memory usage from where it is now.

Comment: Okey, i see, I'll probably give it a shot then. Again, thank you for the help either way